# Window title truncation when using Window::set_title with gtkmm

Tags: c++, cross-platform, gtk, truncate, gtkmm

I am trying to rename the title of my application's main window, but when trying so, the name get truncated. I tried to see if it was a conversion problem but I realy can't find why this happen. Try this little program.
Hit cancel to see the default application name in the title bar, but if you choose a file, it should display the first line of the file as title but instead truncated it... The trucation is always 3 caracters before the end of the string, and three dots "..." is added.

What am I doing wrong?? or is it a bug with my gtkmm version or something? I use gtkmm-2.4
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Gtk;
using namespace Glib;

class AppWindow : public Window {
 public:
    AppWindow();
 protected:
    void onMenuFileOpen();
 private:
    ustring app_name;
    void OpenScript(const ustring sScriptFile);
};

AppWindow::AppWindow() {
    app_name = "default app_name, very long name, with !!^spectal caractères à afficher, and there is no name truncation";
    //set_title(app_name);  
    set_default_size(600, 600);

    onMenuFileOpen();

}

void AppWindow::onMenuFileOpen() {
    FileChooserDialog dialog("Choose a file", FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN);
    dialog.set_transient_for(*this);

    //Add response buttons the the dialog:
    dialog.add_button(Stock::CANCEL, RESPONSE_CANCEL);
    dialog.add_button(Stock::OPEN, RESPONSE_OK);

    //Plain text filter
    FileFilter filter_text;
    filter_text.set_name("plain text");
    filter_text.add_mime_type("text/plain");
    dialog.add_filter(filter_text);

    //Show the dialog and wait for a user response:
    if(dialog.run() == RESPONSE_OK) {
        OpenScript(dialog.get_filename());
    }
    //HERE, I RENAME THE WINDOW
    set_title(app_name);
    cout << app_name << endl;
}

void AppWindow::OpenScript(const ustring sScriptFile) {
    RefPtr<IOChannel> file = IOChannel::create_from_file(sScriptFile,"r");
    IOStatus status;
    ustring one_line;

    if(file->get_flags() & IO_FLAG_IS_READABLE) {
        status = file->read_line(one_line);
        app_name=one_line;
    }
    file->close();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Main kit(argc, argv);

    AppWindow window;
    //Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
    Main::run(window);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally found the solution myself. I write it here in case someone else gets the same issue. I don't know if it is a bug or what, but seems like GTK substitutes the three last characters before a '\n' to '...'. In other words, the string used to rename the window must not contain any '\n' or else set_title will not show the full name (it will stop three characters before '\n').

Therefore, In my case, since I used 'getline()', I simply removed the '\n' from the end of the string.

```
app_name.erase(app_name.end()-1);
```

Note that I had to use a 'std::string' instead of a 'Gtk::ustring' since it doesn't handle the 'operator-' on 'end()' function.

Comment: it's probably the window manager rather than GTK doing this. It's likely confused by the \n into thinking the title won't fit in available space, so trying to ellipsize it.

Comment: That means the example you gave was never problematic for you.

Answer (score 3):

Works fine here.

- maybe your file is not in UTF-8 encoding?
- it's normal for the title to be truncated if it's longer than the space in the titlebar?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the truncation is always half the title bar, no matter if I resize or anything.
All my files are UTF8, just double-checked. What is your Gtkmm/Gtk+/Glib version and on what OS, so I can see if it is an issue with my GTK libraries.

Comment: you're saying the truncation varies as you resize the window, but is always half the title bar? If so I'd definitely tend to blame the theme or the window manager, since apparently gtk is providing the whole string, and the WM varies how much it chops off. If it's a gtk problem you'd expect the string to be missing characters, if it's a WM problem you'd expect part of the string to not get painted. i.e. gtk provides string, WM paints it. I tested gtkmm 2.20.3 / gtk 2.22.0 on Ubuntu Maverick.

Comment: Actually, I have the same OS... And I just figured out that the truncation is always the last three characters, replaced by three dots... I will try to use a fresh new account tomorrow to see if it is a Gnome configuration problem.